# The reset password token is invalid in laravel 5.8 while reseting the password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, reset-password

I am new to laravel. I am using the laravel built-in Auth command. I have functionality where I reset the password of the user and I send the token in the email. I check the value of both the tokens are the same but I am getting and error that the password reset token is invalid.

I have implemented the same functionality that is provided by the laravel and I have done some customization on the controller in reset password controller. The token that I receive in the URL and in the email are the same, but I am not able to reset the password.

```
RegisterController.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Mail\verifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255',],
            'type_of_user' => ['required'],
//            'contact_number' => ['required',  'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ],[
            "first_name.required"=>"Please enter :attribute",
            "last_name.required"=>"Please enter :attribute",
            "type_of_user.required"=>"Please select :attribute",
//            "contact_number.required"=>"Please enter :attribute",
//            "contact_number.unique"=>"this :attribute is already in use",
            "email.required"=>"Please enter :attribute",
            "email.unique"=>"this :attribute is already in use",
            "password.required"=>"Please enter :attribute",
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {



       Session::flash('success','you have successfully registered on the website please verify your email to activate your account!');


// session()->flash('registered','you have successfully registered on the website please verify your email to activate your account!!!');

        $user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'contact_number' => $data['contact_number'],
            'role_id' => $data['type_of_user'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

            'verifyToken' => Str::random(40)
        ]);

        $thisUser = User::findOrFail($user->id);
        $this->sendVerificationMail($thisUser);

        return $user;
    }


//    public function register(Request $request)
//    {
//        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
//
//        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
//
//        $this->guard()->login($user);
//        Session::flash('success', 'you have successfully registered on the website please verify your email to activate your account!!!');
//
//
//
//        return $this->registered($request, $user)
//            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
//    }



    public function register(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        // validate the form

        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        // add the user
        $this->create($request->all());


        // redirect user
//        return redirect($this->redirectPath());


        return redirect('/login')->with("success","You have successfully registered on the website please verify your email to activate your account!!!");


    }


    public function sendVerificationMail($thisUser)
    {
        Mail::to($thisUser['email'])->send(new verifyEmail($thisUser));
    }

    public function verifyEmail()
    {

        return view('email.verifyEmailfirst');
    }


    public function  email_verified(){

        return view('email.email-verified');
    }


    public  function  sendEmailDone($email,$verifyToken){


        $current_date_time = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

       $user = User::where(["email"=>$email,"verifyToken"=>$verifyToken])->first();

        if($user)
        {
             $verified = User::where(["email"=>$email,"verifyToken"=>$verifyToken])->update(["status"=>1,"verifyToken"=>null,"email_verified_at"=> $current_date_time ]);

             if($verified)
             {
                 return redirect ('email-verified');


             }
        }

    }
}


Routes.php

Route::get('/verify-email', 'Auth\RegisterController@verifyEmail')->name('verifyEmail');
Route::get('/verify/{email}/{verifyToken}', 'Auth\RegisterController@sendEmailDone')->name('sendEmailDone');
Route::get('/email-verified', 'Auth\RegisterController@email_verified')->name('email_verified');
```

When I submit the form it should change the password but it is saying the reset password token is invalid. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked if the token in your link is the same as the token that was saved to the database?  The issue might be that either a wrong token is saved, or even none at al.

Comment: hello i guess the problem is in the token  compare the both the Laravel is saving different token in the database and it is sending me different token in the email.  can you please briefly explain to me how Laravel generates the password reset token and how it sends the same token in email ?

Comment: Does your database have the 'password_resets' table? Laravel stores the tokens there, not in the User model. From your code it seems you are trying to send a verification mail, not a pass reset mail.

Comment: well thanks for the suggestion the error was the reset password token was not the same as of in the password_resets table in the database i have fully customize the functionality and make it work .